# How to make NSDictionary and parse it in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary

I have to make below NSDictionary

```
{"aps":{"sound":"default",
"alert":{"body":"From Franklin Av To Grand Army Plaza03:56:30 - 03:58:30",
"action-loc-key":"View"},"badge":1},"user_id":"1","start_station_id":"239N","node_id":"75"}
```

also I want Parse it and get "From Franklin Av To Grand Army Plaza03:56:30 - 03:58:30" text and all id's i.e 1,239N,75. Please if any one knows how to do it help me.

Comment: The string you are getting is dictionary?I mean the above string you are getting is in which format?

Comment: I want make that string as NSDictionary and parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the above response mostly NSData (data in the below snippet) I presume, in a NSDictionary:

```
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization 
                          JSONObjectWithData:data
                          options:kNilOptions 
                          error:&error];
```

Now you have the NSDictionary json. Use `[[[json objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"] valueForKey:@"body"]` for your first requirement, and for the second requirement use:

```
[json valueForKey:@"user_id"];
[json valueForKey:@"start_station_id"];
[json valueForKey:@"node_id"];
```

Note: iOS 5 and above has NSJSONSerialization that can handle JSON responses.

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you are using iOS 5.0 and above:

```
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                         options:kNilOptions 
                                                           error:&error];
```

where responseData is NSData(response you are getting) not NSString.
And to get text "From Franklin Av To Grand Army Plaza03:56:30 - 03:58:30" you can use:

```
[[[json objectForKey@"aps"] objectForKey@"alert"] objectForKey@"body"];
```

Answer (score 0):

use [TouchJSON](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON)

```
    // i think you will have a downloaded NSData here, but..you gave us a string
    NSData *responseData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *error = nil;
    CJSONDeserializer *deserializer = [CJSONDeserializer deserializer];
    deserializer.nullObject = NULL;
    NSDictionary *JSON_dictionary = [deserializer deserialize:responseData error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[[JSON_dictionary objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"] objectForKey:@"body"]);
```

You can use any other JSON parser library also, [there are many of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286087/best-json-library-to-use-when-developing-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
NSDictionary *menu = (NSDictionary *) [data objectForKey:@"aps"];
NSDictionary *data = (NSDictionary *) [menu objectForKey:@"alert"];
NSString *com=(NSString *) [data objectForKey:@"body"]];
NSLog(@"Body= %@",com);
```